# How to avoid use of `lexical-let`

Tags: elisp-macros, lexical-scoping, let-binding, lexical-binding

I have a macro that intends to creates a closure:

```
; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defmacro repro ()
  (let ((kmap-sym (gensym "kmap-")))
    `(let ((,kmap-sym (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key ,kmap-sym "a"
         (lambda () (interactive) (message "kmap is %s" ,kmap-sym)))
       ,kmap-sym)))

;; only works when lexical-binding: t in the current file
(funcall (lookup-key (repro) "a"))
```

Although `lexical-binding` is `t` in the file where the macro is defined, `(funcall (lookup-key (repro) "a"))` fails with the error `(void-variable kmap-30252)` whenever it is evaluated in a different file where `lexical-binding` is `nil`.

Since I can't control where the macro will be used, I considered going back to using `lexical-let` for the inner let in the example, which does work regardless of where the macro is invoked.

```
(defmacro repro ()
  (let ((kmap-sym (gensym "kmap-")))
    `(lexical-let ((,kmap-sym (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key ,kmap-sym "a"
         (lambda () (interactive) (message "kmap is %s" ,kmap-sym)))
       ,kmap-sym)))

;; this works in any file
(funcall (lookup-key (repro) "a"))
```

But `lexical-let` requires `cl`, which I would like to avoid, and unfortunately `lexical-let` is not defined in `cl-lib`.

What options do I have for creating a closure?

Should the macroexpansion of `repro` always expand into lexical bindings given that `lexical-binding` is `t` where the macro is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure if the result meets your expectation.

```
(defun foo (keymap)
  `(lambda () (interactive) (message "kmap is %s" ',keymap)))

(defmacro repro ()
  (let ((kmap-sym (gensym "kmap-")))
    `(let ((,kmap-sym (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key ,kmap-sym "a"
         (foo ,kmap-sym))
       ,kmap-sym)))

(setq lexical-binding nil)
;; => nil

(funcall (lookup-key (repro) "a"))
;; => "kmap is (keymap (97 lambda nil (interactive) (message kmap is %s (quote #0))))"

(setq lexical-binding t)
;; => t

(funcall (lookup-key (repro) "a"))
;; => "kmap is (keymap (97 lambda nil (interactive) (message kmap is %s (quote #0))))"
```

The following does the same without using a top-level defun.

```
(defmacro repro ()
  (let ((kmap-sym (gensym "kmap-"))
        (fun (lambda (keymap)
               `(lambda () (interactive) (message "kmap is %s" ',keymap)))))
    `(let ((,kmap-sym (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key ,kmap-sym "a"
         (,fun ,kmap-sym))
       ,kmap-sym)))
```

Comment: I was considering something like this based on the way one can create a javascript closure. But I wasn't sure if there was another alternative. I was also hoping to provide this closure anonymously instead of relying on a top-level function.

Comment: @erjoalgo You can put the top-level function into the macro, (let ((f (lambda (keymap) `(lambda () ...))))), it does the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is likely not representative of the actual code you're using, but a good solution might be to create the closure in the macro and return the closure, instead of returning code which may or may not turn into a closure depending on `lexical-binding`:

```
(defmacro repro ()
  (let* ((kmap-sym (gensym "kmap-")))
    `(let ((,kmap-sym (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key ,kmap-sym "a"
          ',(lambda () (interactive) (message "kmap is %S" (symbol-value kmap-sym))))
       ,kmap-sym)))
```

The other option I use nowadays is to do something like

```
(defmacro ...
  (if (not lexical-binding)
      (error "Macro `foo` can't be used with dynamic binding"))
    ...))
```

the variable `lexical-binding` can be relied upon (while expanding the macro) to indicate whether the returned code will be run with lexical or dynamic binding.

Comment: I tried this solution https://pastebin.com/8ntq4fTJ but it still failed for me with "Symbol’s value as variable is void: kmap-sym"

Comment: @erjoalgo: Was this code placed in a file that uses `lexical-binding`?

Comment: yes  (insert filler chars)

Answer (score 2):

There is an ugly workaround using `eval` with the optional argument `LEXICAL` set to `t`.

```el
(defmacro repro ()
  (let ((kmap-sym (gensym "kmap-")))
    `(eval
      '(let ((,kmap-sym (make-sparse-keymap)))
         (define-key ,kmap-sym "a"
           (lambda () (interactive) (message "kmap is %s" ,kmap-sym)))
         ,kmap-sym)
      t)))
```

It is ugly since the associated quoting prevents byte-compilation.

Comment: it's nice to know this exists, although I'd prefer `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))` over this.